# Getting 403 (Forbidden) React + Django

Tags: reactjs, django, http-status-code-403, django-cors-headers

when I try to delete or edit a task(todo), I get `DELETE http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tasks/4/ 403 (Forbidden)`. But, when I want just to get tasks, everything works. Maybe the problem in CORS. I have 'corsheaders' in INSTALLED_APPS and 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware' in MIDDLEWARE

serializers.py

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('pk', 'title', 'created_at', 'is_done')
```

settings.py

```
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    'DELETE',
    'GET',
    'OPTIONS',
    'PATCH',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
]
```

App.js

```
function removeTodo(id){
        axios.delete(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tasks/${id}`)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In views.py I didn't make a @api_view(['DELETE']) etc. And add it to urls.py
views.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def taskList(request):
    tasks = Task.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    serializer = TaskSerializer(tasks, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['POST'])
def taskCreate(request):
    serializer = TaskSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()

    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['DELETE'])
def taskDelete(request, pk):
    task = Task.objects.get(id=pk)
    task.delete()

    return Response('Item successfully delete!')
```

Answer (score 1):

In your settings.py just add:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        
    )
}
```

This works because with these settings we get to use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.